# MSP430 printf function executes too slow

Tags: microcontroller, c, uart, msp430, microprocessor

I try to use Sky mote (MSP430 F1611 + CC2420) to read the data from I2C sensor with 100Hz sampling frequency and write the data to serial port (USB). I tried a couple of tests and realized that the total output data have a sampling frequency of 78Hz. I used rtimer to profile my sampling and printing code and found the print function slows down the entire process. Here are some profiling outputs:

```
start 50628
15490,f074,20,3b8c,ffab,49,ffcf,fb70
end 51189
start 51293
15491,f0a8,fff4,3ba4,ffc6,24,ffd8,fb90
end 51880
start 51984
15492,f094,20,3b30,ffa7,5b,fff3,fb70
end 52544
start 52647
15493,f118,bc,3ce0,ffab,70,fffc,fb90
end 53207
start 53311
15494,f030,1b0,3b44,ffa9,1f7,1f,fb80
end 53871
```

The rtimer has 4098*8 ticks for one second. Here we can clearly see that the printing takes about 560 ticks (17ms). If the sampling frequency is 100Hz, the printing function should be completed within 10ms (327 ticks).

The embedded system I am using is Contiki OS and the baud rate is 115200 (maximum baud rate). The sensor sample contains 112-bits signed int.

Here is my code:

```
mpu_data_union samples;
int m=mpu_sample_all(&samples);
printf("start %u\n",RTIMER_NOW());
printf("%lu,%x,%x,%x,%x,%x,%x,%x\n",
  counterxx,samples.data.accel_x,samples.data.accel_y,
  samples.data.accel_z,samples.data.gyro_x,
  samples.data.gyro_y,samples.data.gyro_z,
  samples.data.temperature);
printf("end %u\n",RTIMER_NOW());
```

I hope some people with previous experience on optimizing printf or UART in general could provide some suggestions.

Comment: I don't see a '?' in your post.

Comment: You may find that it's sending a byte at a time; try snprintf into a buffer and then print the buffer.

Comment: Inbuilt printf functions etc. can often be quite slow as they're general-purpose and not always the most efficient for the job at hand. Have a look at the source & see if you can make a faster & more specific routine.

Comment: This space is reserved for question.  This is not a show and tell site.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, are you using a USB CDC serial port or a UART feeding a UART->USB converter? If the latter your baud rate may be too low.

You can optimize the output of hex values by making the assumption that you always want to print 4 characters. Then it is a simple case of generating a character for each nibble. A lookup table would probably be the fastest option.

Comment: I think it is latter case. However, I look at the source code where the baud rate is defined, 115200 is the largest possible rate. I tried to increase to 230400 but error occurred.